# How to hide inappbrowser location url

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, inappbrowser

Good day everyone, please I am trying to integrate payment gateway in my ionic app, the code is working well but the only issue I have is how to hide the inAppBrowser location URL

**This is how it opens**

[image: THis is how it opens]

**I want it to open like this without the URL bar**
[image: I want it to open like this without the URL bar]

Here is the code below. Thanks

```
constructor(
  private rave: Rave, 
  private ravePayment: RavePayment, 
  private misc: Misc,
  private iab: InAppBrowser,
  ) { }

...


this.rave.init(PRODUCTION_FLAG, "YOUR_PUBLIC_KEY")
      .then(_ => {
        var paymentObject = this.ravePayment.create({
          customer_email: "nuser@example.com",
          amount: 2000,
          customer_phone: "23412345667",
          currency: "NGN",
          txref: "rave-1234567",
          meta: [{
              metaname: "flightID",
              metavalue: "AP1234"
          }]
      })
        this.rave.preRender(paymentObject)
          .then(secure_link => {
            secure_link = secure_link +" ";
            const browser: InAppBrowserObject = this.rave.render(secure_link, this.iab);
            browser.on("loadstop")
                .subscribe((event: InAppBrowserEvent) => {
                  if(event.url.indexOf('https://your-redirect-url') != -1) {
                    if(this.rave.paymentStatus(url) == 'failed') {
                      this.alertCtrl.create({
                        title: "Message",
                        message: "Oops! Transaction failed"
                      }).present();
                    }else {
                      this.alertCtrl.create({
                        title: "Message",
                        message: "Transaction successful"
                      }).present();
                    }
                    browser.close()
                  }
                })
          }).catch(error => {
            // Error or invalid paymentObject passed in
          })
      })
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For Cordova In App Browser, you can pass the options object with `location` as `no`

```
var ref = cordova.InAppBrowser.open(url, target, options);
```

Your code will become

```
this.rave.render(secure_link, this.iab,{location: 'no'})
```

[Reference](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-inappbrowser#cordovainappbrowseropen)

EDIT -

Try to create an iab object and then pass it to this.rave.render

```
let browser = this.theInAppBrowser.create(secure_link, _blank,{location: 'no'});
```

And then pass it like this

```
this.rave.render(secure_link, browser)
```

Comment: Thanks for your quick response, but I got this error message "Expected 2 arguments, but got 3" when I included the 3rd argument.